# Having problems with scope of lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

Let's use this method that I'm trying to call as an example:

```
 MyMethod<MyType, string>(Expression<Func<MyType, string>> expression)
```

If I try to dynamically build the following expression `x => x.Name` and pass it to the method, everything works just fine:

```
var pi = typeof(MyType).GetProperty("Name");
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyType), "x");
MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(pe, pi);
var exp = Expression.Lambda(me, pe);
```

Now let's imagine that in the exact same scope, I'm trying to build this expression instead `x => item.Name` using the following code, obviously item being different than the input parameter x:

```
var item = new MyType() { Name = "My name" };
var pi = t.GetProperty("Name");
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyType), "x");
ParameterExpression pe2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyType), "item");
MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(pe2, pi);
var exp = Expression.Lambda(me, pe);
```

When I try to call MyMethod I get the following error, probably because there's no variable "item" in the scope where MyMethod is called (which is not where I build the expression):

```
variable 'item' of type 'MyType' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

How can I build this expression in such a way that it won't throw this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the scope of the lambda, the `item` bit is a constant - it's not a variable parameter to the invocation.

So the following should be closer:

```
var item = new MyType() { Name = "My name" };
var pi = t.GetProperty("Name");
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyType), "x");
ConstantExpression ce = Expression.Constant(typeof(MyType), item);
MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(ce, pi);
var exp = Expression.Lambda(me, pe);
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly right, everything works now, just one thing for anyone else implementing this code, it's Expression.Constant(item, typeof(MyType)), notice it's item and not "item", it wants the actual reference. Intellisense will let you know anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**The string `"item"` is not related in any way to the local variable `item`.** If you want your constructed lambda expression to capture the value of the local variable `item`, then instead of `Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyType), "item")` you need `Expression.Constant(item)`.

Comment: Note that most likely does what's needed here, but it behaves differently than normal lambda, because `item` is no longer part of a closure. This means that if you use `Expression.Constant(item)` and then change the value of `item`, the value in the expression won't change.

Comment: You're right, but there's no way to tell the compiler 'lift this local variable into a closure and give me a reference to the closure' except by having it compile a lambda expression. If you want C# closure semantics in a hand-crafted expression, you'll have to simulate it.